# Limiting the CPU utilization of a user in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu-usage

I want to know if there is any way to limit the number of cpu usage by the user name in windows? For example, there are 8 cores and I want to limit the global cpu usage of a user to 6. So, he can not run more than 6 serial jobs (each use one core).

In Linux, that can be done via scripting. But I haven't see any similar thing even with powershell scripts. Does that mean, it can not be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword for this is **Affinity**.
Affinity starts at 0 being first core.
Affinity is a bitmap

`10000000 = first core
01000000 = second core
11000000 = first and second core
00100000 = third core
10100000 = first and third core
11100000 = first second and third core`

```
function Set-Affinity([string]$Username,[int[]]$core){
    [int]$affinty = 0
    $core | %{ $affinty += [math]::pow(2,$_)}
    get-process -IncludeUserName | ?{$_.UserName -eq $Username} | %{
        $_.ProcessorAffinity = $affinty
    }
}

Set-Affinity -username "TESTDOMAIN\TESTUSER" -core 0,1,2,3
```

Comment: i think you might be looking in the wrong place. Task Manager >  Details >  right-click on a process and select Affinity. Then run my command and then check again and see if affinity changed

Comment: No. The same happens.